# Can rectangle be used as a parent class (tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter

when I have free time at work, i'm fooling around with python (2.6), and I thought I'd try and create a [game of life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life). For that purpose I want to make a class for the different cells, which would be drawn on the canvas like rectangles, but would have more properties like whether they are alive or dead, etc.

I saw that the canvas module in the tkinter library has a rectangle class, but it says this module is obsolete, and in the tkinter module itself, all i can find is a function pertaining to rectangles

Am I missing something... Is it possible at all to use rectangle as a parent class... (and maybe am I totally wrong in trying to make the cells instances of a class; still as a I'm only beginning to get into programming i'd like to try and make it like that for the experience)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rectangle class that you can use as a parent class. However, you can create your own class that represents a rectangle with just a few lines of code.

For example:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, canvas, coords, fill, outline=None):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.outline = outline if outline is not None else fill
        self.fill = fill
        self.canvas_id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(
            coords, outline=self.outline, fill=self.fill)
```

You can use it like this:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(...)
r1 = Rectangle(canvas, (50,50, 150, 150), "red")
r2 = Rectangle(canvas, (100, 50, 150, 150), "green")
...
```

You could then create a subclass named `Cell` which takes a row and column rather than actual x/y coordinates, and has a method `set_state` which changes the color:

```
class Cell(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, canvas, row, column):
        # make a 50x50 rectangle in the given row, column
        x0 = column * 50
        y0 = row * 50
        x1 = x0 + 50
        y1 = y0 + 50
        self.state = None
        super(Cell, self).__init__(canvas, (x0, y0, x1, y1), "gray")

    def set_state(self, state):
        self.state = state
        color = "green" if state == "alive" else "red"
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.canvas_id, fill=color, outline=color)
```

You would use it like this:

```
# place a cell at row zero, column zero, and
# set its state to "alive"
cell = Cell(canvas, 0, 0)
cell.set_state("alive")
```